# Adb command(s) to get screen state and locked state

Tags: adb, lock-screens

**Background:**

I'm using automated tests on many different variants of devices (*Samsung tablets and smartphones such as Galaxy A5, S8, S7 etc.*) where the devices have different versions of Android (*6.0, 6.0.1, 7.0 and 7.1.1*) - all in varying combinations.

Some of my tests require locking the screen (turning it off) and then turning it on and PIN-ing in. I have not been able to find a (universal) adb-command to get the phones' state. Ideally, I would like **one** command to tell me in which of the following states the phone is in:

1. Screen turned off (Assumed locked as well)
2. Screen turned on, locked
3. Screen turned on, unlocked

My best solution *so far* is to use the following 2 (bash terminal) commands:

```
#1:
adb shell dumpsys display | grep "mScreenState"

#2:
adb shell service call trust 7
```

Command #1 tells me whether the screen is on, off or "dozed".

Command #2 tells me whether the phone is locked or unlocked.

**Questions:**

Is there a single adb command which can give me the information I need? Is this command compatible with the Android versions listed above?

<strike>On Android version 6.* command #2 **always** indicates that the phone is locked. What is the "Android 6.* compatible" alternative of command #2?</strike>  ----> *By pure chance I found that "service call trust **6**" works as expected on Android 6.* devices!*

**Note:**

The resource I've found that most closely resembles my issue is the following [SO question/response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35276479/6231936). However, not all of the devices have/use NFC so the following command (although compatible with most devices/versions) is not acceptable in my tests:

```
adb shell dumpsys nfc | grep 'mScreenState='
```

Since timing is an issue, the proposed solution (best answer in the link) is not acceptable either.

Answer (score 3):

I am a Windows fanboy, so the solution contains `find` instead of using `grep`, just replace find with grep.

```
adb shell dumpsys power | find "mWakefulness="
adb shell dumpsys power | find "mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker="
```

> Screen **OFF** and **Locked** = mWakefulness=**Asleep** & 
>   mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker=**false**
>
> Screen **ON** and **Locked** = mWakefulness=**Awake** & 
>   mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker=**false**
>
> Screen **ON** and **Unlocked** = mWakefulness=**Awake** & 
>   mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker=**true**

**P.S:** I've tested it on **Android 7.0**, don't know if it'll work with other versions.

Answer (score 1):

As I've run into this recently and since using the Daydream lockscreen is not an requirement on Android, here's some newer variables that are (probably) universal.

They *should* be available starting at **Android M (6.0 / API 23)** since they come with Doze mode; I've **confirmed** them with Android 10 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 and Android 12 on a Pixel 4 XL.

```
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle | grep '\bm[A-Z]'
mLightEnabled=true  mDeepEnabled=true
mForceIdle=false
mUseMotionSensor=true mMotionSensor={Sensor name="Significant Motion", vendor="Google", version=1, type=17, maxRange=1.0, resolution=1.0, power=0.25, minDelay=-1}
mScreenOn=false
mScreenLocked=true
mNetworkConnected=true
mCharging=false
mMotionActive=true
mNotMoving=false
mMotionListener.activatedTimeElapsed=36192
mLastMotionEventElapsed=0
mLocating=false mHasGps=false mHasNetwork=false mLocated=false
mState=INACTIVE mLightState=IDLE
mInactiveTimeout=+30m0s0ms
mNextAlarmTime=+22m36s283ms
mNextIdleDelay=+10m0s0ms (flex=+2m0s0ms)
mNextLightAlarmTime=-23s699ms
mCurLightIdleBudget=+1m0s0ms
```

Of course, the prize jewels here are `mScreenOn` and `mScreenLocked`, which are booleans doing exactly what you went them to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk to spit out the answer you want.  Here is a quick and dirty awk script I whipped up just now:

```
adb shell dumpsys power | awk -F"[ =]" '/mWakefulness=/ { mw=$NF; }
/mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker=/ {mh=$NF;}
END {
  print mw
  print mh
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

has answered in [Is there a way to check if Android device screen is locked via adb? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275828/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-android-device-screen-is-locked-via-adb/60037241#60037241) and copy to here:

- My Phone: `XiaoMi 9`

  - Android: `10`

## use adb to check status of screen locked

### method 1: (universal) use `mDreamingLockscreen`

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys window | grep mDreamingLockscreen`
- Output:

  - `mShowingDream=false mDreamingLockscreen=true mDreamingSleepToken=null` -> Screen **Locked**

    - no matter Screen is `ON` or `OFF`
  - `mShowingDream=false mDreamingLockscreen=false mDreamingSleepToken=null` -> Scrren **Unlocked**

### method 2: use `nfc` (if android has NFC module)

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys nfc | grep 'mScreenState='`
- Output:

  - `mScreenState=OFF_LOCKED` -> Screen OFF and Locked
  - `mScreenState=ON_LOCKED` -> Screen ON and Locked
  - `mScreenState=ON_UNLOCKED` -> Screen ON and Unlocked

Comment: I would say that it does matter whether the screen is on or off. If the screen is off, then I would first need to turn it on before I can input pin (by simulating menu press/swipe) and then PIN in. How would i input PIN if the screen is off?

Comment: Not quite, only universal if they're implementing the Daydream lock… Samsung, for example, isn't.